# Jssor List Slider Remove Thumbs when responsive so Image width scales at 100%

Tags: list, slider, jssor

Hi am making a slider based on the List Slider http://www.jssor.com/demos/list-slider.html

I am trying to hide the thumbs only for screens max-width 770px.

When removing them with css then they don't appear, but the problem is that the image in the slide doesn't resize at 100% width. I have tried with css making the whole slides container to become the size of the whole slider container. so it fills the space of the hidden thumbs. But the responsiveness doesn't really work properly. Can anybody help?

I reckon this would have to be done in the script instead of with css. But my javascript knowledge is not that great.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow 2 steps below,

1. add id to thumbnail navigator

   ```
       <div u="thumbnavigator" id="slider1_thumbnavigator" ...
   ```
2. replace

   ```
       var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
   ```

   with

   ```
       var windowWidth = $(window).width();

       if (windowWidth <= 770) {
           $("#slider1_thumbnavigator").remove();
           $("#slider1_container").width("600px");
       }

       var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This removes the thumbnails but the slider doesn't fill the width, there is a space where the thumbnails are. So the following works for me, you have add another ID to the container after slider1_container

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        if (windowWidth <= 770) {

            $("#slider1_thumbnavigator").remove();
            $("#slider1_container").width("100%");
            $("#slider1_container #theSlides").css("left",0);
        }


        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

I tried to add this in the  ScaleSlider() function as I would like jssor to adjust automatically when people are resizing the browser during testing but somehow it didn't work in there. It only works on the initialization